# Array inside array knockout how to?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the an array.

and I have a table:

and this is my template:

What I want to do is for each VegType have 1 checkbox for Carrot, 1 for Potato, 1 one for ETC.

so what will show is :

and so on so forth...

but I want the VegID and VegiType to show next to each check box.

Hope someone helps with this.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your viewmodel code? Try posting this in a fiddle so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you just want another foreach wrapped around the generation of the checkboxes:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: VegType" >
    <label data-bind="text: Vegitype"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr:{id: VegID}"/>
```

UPDATE:

Ok, so it looks like you want to do something like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="a-template">
<tr>
    <td>
    <span data-bind="text: INFOTEXTAREA"></span>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span data-bind="text: ID"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: VegType">
    <li>
        <label data-bind="text: Vegitype"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr:{id: VegID}" />
    </li>
    </ul>

</tr>
</script>
```

Comment: My first foreach will run and create the text on top of the text area and the text area, but each time a text and text area is created.. it will also creat 3 checkboxes Carrot, Potato, ETC. for the same table body.

Comment: Thanks this works :) I am just wondering how it recoganizes that VegType is an array inside an array ;/

Comment: You're welcome.  You defined `VegType` as an array using the `[]` syntax so knockout knows :)